# Uploading and querying images

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am currently attempting to upload images from my HTML form to a MySQL BLOB column.

Here is the current relevant code for my HTML code (input file type is just a placeholder, I will of course change it out to whatever it must be. These values are in table data form, but I condensed it down to be easier to read)

```
                    <form method="post" action="inspectionprocessing.php">
                    <input type="text" name ="unit" value="">
                    <input type="text" name ="notes" value="">
                    <input type="file" name ="media">   
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Inspections" name="submit">
                    </form>
```

Here is the code to insert into MySQL.

```
         //Establishing variables
     $unitNumber = $_POST["unit"];
     $unitNotes = $_POST ["notes"];
     $unitMedia = $_POST ["media"];

         // Create connection
     $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password); 
     // Check connection
     if (!$con) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }
     echo ""; 
     
        //Query database
     $sql = "INSERT into inspect.building_1 (Unit, Notes, Media) values ('$unitNumber','$unitNotes', '$unitMedia')";
     $inspection = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Here is the code to display information from the database

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inspect.building_1 "; 
$apartments = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
while($apartment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($apartments)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $apartment ["Unit"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $apartment ["Notes"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $apartment ["Media"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $apartment ["Date"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $apartment ["InspectionID"] . "</td>";
```

In sum, I m looking for HTML code to upload multiple images to a table under one InspectionID in the database. I need the database to store the images and display them on a separate page. I am totally open to a file path, but I will need all of the necessary code - I am very much a beginner here doing it all for the first time. Thank you so much for your help!

Images if you want to know what it looks like.
[image: UI to upload pictures]
[image: Datbase Structure]
[image: UI Display area]

*Note: Database connections and everything works, I only need help with images*

Comment: Right off the bat I can see your form tag is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which you'll need when you're uploading files

Comment: BTW your code is open to SQL injection because it's not using prepared statements or parameterized queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for more info.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: _"but I will need all of the necessary code"_ - That's not really how this site works. We can help you sort out issues with your existing code, but we're not here to write it for you. The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) has a pretty good tutorial about handling uploads in PHP with proper explanations. I would recommend that you start there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form so your form can accept retrieving files
and second you cannot retrieve data with the `$_POST` super global you have to use the `$_FILES` super global
Here is the code

```html
    <form class="forms-sample" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="media">Media Image</label>
              <input type="file"  name="media">
          </div>
    </form>
    
    $unitMedia = $_FILES['media']['name'];
    $unitMedia_temp = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];


    move_uploaded_file($unitMedia_temp, "img/$unitMedia");
```

and if you want to insert your image to database you can use `$unitMedia` to insert it
That is all what i have to say And I wish that helped you

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat I can see your form tag is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which you'll need when you're uploading files.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="inspectionprocessing.php">
```

You can get the blob data right from the uploaded data. It's not going to be a $_POST variable, it's going to be a $_FILES variable. Something like this in inspectionprocessing.php:

```
 $unitMedia = file_get_contents($_FILES['media']["tmp_name"]);
```

Also, it's highly recommended to validate that the uploaded image is actually an image, is not too big, etc. There's some validation stuff you can check out here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Also also, its best to get in the practice of using prepared statements for your MySQL inserts and updates to prevent SQL injection. Start this habit now! https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp